# what can cause 66 volts at 110 outlets in my moble home

Tags: walls, receptacle

I went to hookup a 110 volt hottub, but when we plugged it in we only got 66 volts. I then tried another plug in the house - 66 volts.
I went to another building, my shop, which has its own breaker box, but got the same there - 66 volts. A 220 volt oulet there only had 134 volts.
I don't know whats up.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/187382/why-am-i-measuring-60v-at-some-outlets

Comment: What voltages do you measure at that 220 outlet, not just hot-to-other-hot, but from each hot to neutral and/or ground as well?

Comment: Turn off all your 240V breakers on all panels.  And then try your measurements again.

Comment: We need to know what country the OP is in. If European, they might have 3 phase.  I don't know enough about 3phase, but others need to know that to offer the best help possible.

Comment: Are both of these buildings on the same connection to the utility company's power?

Answer (score 1):

Classic sign of a bad neutral connection. It's a dangerous situation and needs the attention of a professional electrician if it is in your house. But FIRST, call your utility, because it might be on their side and they will check that for free. If they don't find anything, they will not help you with your house wiring, that's your problem. But if you call the electrician first and it turns out to be a utility issue, you still owe the electrician for the house call.

Answer (score 0):

134 instead of 240, could be the power company has lost a phase.

check the voltage as near to the supply as you can safely. (eg: unplug your mobile home and measure the outlet that feeds it)